# Function to Sort related products by Product Title in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

how to Sort related products by Product Title in WooCommerce without using a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort related products like this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'BN_order_related_priducts_by_title_asc', 20 );
  function BN_order_related_priducts_by_title_asc( $args ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'title';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
 
    return $args;
}
```

Add the code to the functions.php file of your child theme.

Comment: Great! you're welcome